# Use Error() without throwing exception in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component called `<Error />` which can accept a string or an actual `Error()` object.

This following Jest/Enzyme code works:

```js
it('renders with error prop', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Error error="Foobar" />);
  expect(component.text()).toMatchSnapshot();
  expect(component.text()).toEqual('Foobar');
});
```

However the following does not:

```js
it('renders with new Error() error prop', () => {
  const error = new Error('Foobar');
  const component = shallow(<Error error={error} />);
  expect(component.text()).toMatchSnapshot();
  expect(component.text()).toEqual('Foobar');
});
```

The `new Error()` line causes `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I have tried to wrap it in a `try {} catch () {}` but it just swallows everything.

I have tried doing it as `expect(() => { ... })` but I can't get it to run assertions- it appears this only really works if you want to pipe it into `.toThrow()`

The following looked promising at first, but doesn't actually send anything through to the `error` argument in the catch:

```
it('renders with new Error() error prop', () => {
  try {
    new Error('Foobar');
  }
  catch (error) {
    const component = shallow(<Error error={error} />);
    expect(component.text()).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(component.text()).toEqual('Foobar');
  }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: new Error('Foobar') here is basically calling your Error component, as the answer below suggested, rename your Error component to not overwrite the javascript Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your test file:

```
import Error as ErrorComponent from './error/component.jsx'; //Or wherever this is
```

You could also try to name your Error component differently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agh I'm so stupid. It's been a long day, week... month. Thanks.
I have to just do import ErrorComponent from as I'm not using TS

Comment: There was also a second issue: my <Error /> component was at points throwing an error itself, causing an infinite loop

Comment: No worries man, try to install some code helper tool in VSCode so you don't have to worry about those kind of issues.

Comment: I have loads of stuff that should pick up variables clashing, but  perhaps it has an issue with Error in particular /shrug